# How to change webview content size?

Tags: android, webview

I have main class of the program with the following code

```
public class HTMLViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView web;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( width , height));
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + "web" + "/databases/");
        web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        web.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
        web.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        web.clearView();
        web.measure(10, 10);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.fullscreenmario.com/stable/mario.html");
    }
}
```

When I load page in this webview it is very big, and I cant change this. In mobile Chrome it has normal size

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try one of the following lines: web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); or web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Comment: Almost. But not all part of the screen is render...
Here is screenshot
|https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27865855/Screenshot_2013-10-24-21-19-45.png

Comment: Not sure what the problem appears to be, never encountered this. But you could try the following methods, we use those on a webview that does work correctly:m_webView.setInitialScale(1);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {// Android v3.0+
                        try {
                                m_webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
                m_webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);                
             
m_webView.clearCache(true);

Comment: Nope. Get the same result